# How to add "node_modules" to a downloaded Git repository

Tags: git, github, angular-cli

I have several questions.

The most important one is what's in the title: How do I add node_modules to a downloaded Git repository? I know that "node_modules" has a lot of files and therefore cannot be held in a Git repository. Please list out step by step what I need to do on my Mac laptop.

Also, it seems like I was able to get *node_modules* when I create a new project like this

```
sudo ng new geckos.
```

However, it comes with its own problems. I cannot create a new project in a directory I like. For example, I wanted to create a project in Documents/GitHub/geckos, but it didn't work. Also I got this warning:

> Project name "Documents/GitHub/geckos" is not valid. New project names must start with a letter, and must contain only alphanumeric characters or dashes. When adding a dash the segment after the dash must also start with a letter.

I concluded that it's due to the `/` slash that I wasn't able to create a new folder. So what should I do to create a new project in the right folder I wanted it to be in?

Lastly, when I do create a new project with all the "node_modules" installed, how do I blend or add the repository that I downloaded to this new project? Is it even possible? I heard something about Git pull. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Install what is in the *package.json* file using: `npm install`

We leave vendor files out of the repository because the packages, and their intended versions, are described in that manifest.  If you're using a newer package manager, sometimes there is a lockfile that also stores the specific versions installed.  In that case you would want to commit the lockfile as well, after testing updates, and in accordance with your team's workflow.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you can add **node_modules** to your Git repository even if this is a bad practice. Firstly you should fetch all the modules using the following command.

```
npm install
```

Then, make sure to remove **node_modules** folder from any **.gitignore** file in your project.

Comment: why is it a bad practice?

Comment: @KristinaBressler, it is bad practice first, because there can be over 150 megs of files in the *node_modules* folder. More if you use a lot of packages. Plus, the contents of the folder can be easily replaced by running `npm install`, leaving no need to put them in version control. Manage the versions of packages you use in your *package.json*.

Comment: Tried this and got "fatal: Not a git repository"!